# Removing Word in Subject of Email Exchange 2013

Tags: spam, exchange-2013

So we have an Exchange 2013 environment, with an offsite anti-spam service. Emails that are deemed spam from them get "[Spam]" added to the beginning of the subject before being sent to our mx.

We then have a transport rule that see's that in the subject, and sets that email's SCL to 8, so that the email will end up in the user's Junk Email folder.

Now, what's annoying is, when the user decides to whitelist the email/sender/domain, etc., emails from the same sender will now go into the Inbox as intended, but of course still have that lame [Spam] part at the beginning of the subject.

I don't see a transport rule that can remove the [Spam] from the subject after setting the SCL to 8, but that's what I'd like to do.

Anyone know how I can accomplish that?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: the user can't whitelist at the third part antispam's service ? (as I guess your user could have a login to see which email got blocked or such at the antispam's level with highter scl)

Comment: Doesn't the off-site service have an option for tagging that word in the subject or not?

Comment: Your third party service should add a header, rather than altering the subject line.

Comment: So yes, the third party has a portal, but our customer hates the idea of having to login somewhere else each time to mark an email as not junk.

Comment: I will ask the third party about the header idea and if they can do that. Thanks.

Comment: So they said the only way they offer is adding something to the subject :(  So any ideas how to remove it at the Exchange level?